# Class parameter (generics) for singleton object

Tags: scala

In [his course on Coursera](https://class.coursera.org/progfun-002/class/index), professor Martin Odesrky uses a linked list as an example in a lecture about polymorphism and parameterized classes:

```
package week4

trait List[T] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def head: T
  def tail: List[T]
}
class Cons[T](val head: T, val tail: List[T]) extends List[T] {
  def isEmpty = false
}
class Nil[T] extends List[T] {
  def isEmpty = true
  def head = throw new NoSuchElementException("Nil.head")
  def tail = throw new NoSuchElementException("Nil.tail")
}
object Main extends App {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val lst = new Cons("A", new Cons("B", new Cons("C", new Nil())))
  }
}
```

What bothers me is the instantiation of class Nil in the last lines, `new Nil()`.

How would one define Nil as an `object` instead of as a Scala class, and have it conform to the parameterized type List[T] ?

I'd like to refer to the object Nil as in the following line of code (no instantiation), and make it have the correct type

```
new Cons("A", new Cons("B", new Cons("C", Nil)))
```

Comment: I don't think you can easily implement Nil. My guess is that Nil is actually null, i.e. it is a subctype of _every_ type. In other words, if you make your list covariant in T, I think it works with the builtin Nil of Scala, but I'm guessing here.

Comment: Call me a cheater, but why don't you [look at scala sources](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.1/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L334)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the actual Scala library ([List.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.1/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L1)) here's how it is done,

```
case object Nil extends List[Nothing] { ...
```

Probably in the class he wanted to avoid introducing `Nothing`, which is the [type at the bottom of Scala's type lattice](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Nothing).

Comment: Nothing has actually been mentioned, but he hasn't gotten to covariance yet, which would be needed for making this work.

Answer (score 3):

Given the `trait List[T]` definition of list, you can't do it. That definition means you need a distinct `Nil` for each `T`, since for every `T1` and `T2`, not identical, `List[T1]` is not compatible with `List[T2]`. Since `Nil` must "be a" `List[Tx]`, any `Tx` you pick will be incompatible with all others.

To get around that you need co-variance, which, iirc, is explained a couple of lessons later.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the mix of Kipton's suggestion and my own:

```
trait List[+T] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def head: T
  def tail: List[T]
}
class Cons[+T](val head: T, val tail: List[T]) extends List[T] {
  def isEmpty = false
}
case object Nil extends List[Nothing] {
  def isEmpty = true
  def head = throw new NoSuchElementException("Nil.head")
  def tail = throw new NoSuchElementException("Nil.tail")
}
object ListTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val lst = new Cons("A", new Cons("B", new Cons("C", Nil)))
  }
}
```

btw, your code doesn't compile with my Scala installation. App implements "main", so you have to override it or (as is the intention of App) leave it out.

Notice that you need `List` and `Cons` to be covariant (e.g. `List[+T]`), which basically means for subtype U of T, it also holds that `List[U]` is a subtype of `List[T]` and by extension that List[Nothing] is a subtype of your list.

Comment: Is it necessary to mark Cons covariant as Cons[+T]? I read from the source that the equivalent `final case class ::[B](hd: B, tl: List[B]) extends List[B] with...`

Comment: That class is used for pattern matching with ::. Note the difference between :: the class, and :: the method.

Comment: Which means you can do this lovely wtf-code: 

scala>  ::(42,Nil) :: 43 :: Nil
res2: List[Any] = List(List(42), 43)

scala>  new ::(42,Nil) :: 43 :: Nil